# SQL Join same table on different condition and get count

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have a table with insurance claims. It has ID, Condition that the patient has, ClaimID, EmergencyDepartmentFlag(1 - ED; 0 - NonED. I need to get the results which gives me the count of the claims per condition and count of the ED visit per condition

```
+----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| MemberID | Condition | ClaimID  | EDFlag |
+----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| A123     | COPD      | 34124434 |      1 |
| A526     | COPD      | 34580304 |      0 |
| A693     | COPD      | 23723642 |      1 |
| A645     | DM        | 46534633 |      1 |
+----------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

**Expected output**

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+
| Condition | TotalClaims | EDClaims |
+-----------+-------------+----------+
| COPD      |           3 |        2 |
| DM        |           1 |        1 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

Query

```
SELECT condition, 
       Count(a1.claimid) AS TotalClaims, 
       Count(a2.claimid) AS EDClaims 
FROM   (SELECT memberid, 
               condition, 
               claimid 
        FROM   mytable) a1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT memberid, 
                          condition, 
                          claimid 
                   FROM   mytable 
                   WHERE  edflag = 1) a2 
               ON a1.memberid = A2.memberid 
GROUP  BY condition
```

This query doesn't return the correct result.

Comment: Why do you need `JOIN` at all?  Seems like a simple *aggregation* with `COUNT` and `SUM` to me.

Comment: @PM77-1 you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Use This

```
SELECT
    Condition,
    TotalClaims = COUNT(1),
    EDClaims = SUM(CAST(EDFlag AS INT))
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Condition
```

Demo :

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Condition VARCHAR(50),
    ClaimID BIGINT,
    EDFlag BIT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('COPD',34124434,1),
('COPD',34580304,0),
('COPD',23723642,1),
('DM',46534633,1)

SELECT
    Condition,
    TotalClaims = COUNT(1),
    EDClaims = SUM(CAST(EDFlag AS INT))
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY Condition
```

Result

[image]

Comment: What if there is another column which is a grain of Claim ID. I.e ClaimID is repeating eg: ClaimA has ClaimLine number 1 and ClaimA has ClaimLineNumber 2. So these are two records. How to handle this in query.

Comment: Then it will count each line as separate. Ie; If ClaimA has Line1 and Line2 then, you will get the count as 2

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
Condition,
COUNT(*) AS TotalClaims,
SUM(CASE WHEN EDFlag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EDClaims
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Condition
```